# Not all free font awesome fonts loading in angular 2+ project

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I am using several free Font Awsome icons throughout my project. The majority load just fine for example

```
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
```

shows a magnifying glass icon however

```
<i class="fa fa-sync"></i>
```

does not show anything. Both are listed as "Free" [on the Font Awsome site](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=refresh&m=free)

In my angular.sjon file I have the following reference to Font Awesome;

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss"
        ],
```

In my package-lock.json file;

```
"font-awesome": {
  "version": "4.7.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/font-awesome/-/font-awesome-4.7.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-j6jPBBGhoxr9B7BtKQK7n8gVoTM="
},
```

and in my package.json file;

```
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
```

Why can I not see the icon I am expecting?

I'm relatively new to both Angular and Font Awesome, I would be greatful(i.e. would +1) for guidance if my approach is generally wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fontawesome site now show the version 5 and above and you have install old version.

you need to install this package

```
npm  install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

and to import the style file like this

*style.scss*

```
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. For other readers, "fortawesome" is not a typo. More info can be found at https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome